# Force exit task that requires authentication when user returns from lock screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, client

## Scenario

From activity A: User presses button that directs them to a pin authentication dialog.  If the user enters a valid pin, they are put into activity B.  If invalid, they remain in activity A.

From activity B: User navigates to activity C in **another application**.

User locks the device.

User unlocks the device.

## What happens

User is back in activity C.

## Desired behavior

User is thrown back into activity A.

## Question

How is it possible to launch activity C in such a way that the user is kicked out when they try to return to it from lock screen?

The difficult part here is that I have no control over activity C other than how I send the intent from my application.

Comment: put `finish();` in `onPause()` of the `activity C`

Comment: "The difficult part here is that I have no control over activity C other than how I send the intent from my application."

Comment: If you're opening another application using yours then it's not possible via your application. Maybe a background thread might do it. 

Basically what do you want to do?

Comment: Activity B is protected by a pin, so implicitly, any activity above it in the activity stack should be protected as well.  Once the user leaves the device, I want to guarantee the next person who picks it up knows the pin before having access to activity B (and any sub-activities).  Protecting activity B is easy, it's the sub-activities that are proving to be a challenge.